# How to add size to my add to cart in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cookies

[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08HWt.png)We already completed add to cart functionality,the product has successfully added to my cart,but the problem is that to select size for the product, product having different sizes like footwear:1,2,3,4.if the selected size is 2 then it should be add to my cart.
    we are using below code:

```
//Size

<table><tr><td>Size:</td>
<?php 
                    for($i=0; $i<$sizecount; $i++) { ?>
 <td><button onclick="selectsize(<?php echo $arr[$i];?>)" class="add-size-cart" hef="<?php echo $arr[$i];?>" pef="<?php echo $products['product_id'];?>"><?php echo $arr[$i];?></button></td> <?php } ?></tr></table> 

//Addtocart button

<a href="addcart.php"  class="btn btn-primary add-cart-button" ref="<?php echo $products['product_id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Add to cart</a> 


$(document).ready(function(){
  //set cookie
    //setCookie('sids','1,2,3,4,5','7');
    //deleteCookie('sids');

    //deleteCookie('sids'); 
    var sids=getCookie('sids');
    var size=getCookie('size');
    if(sids== null){
        setCookie('sids','',7);
        sids='';
    }
    $('.add-cart-button').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('ref');
        var aids = [];  //stores array
        if(sids == ''){
            aids.push(id);
            setCookie('sids',aids.toString(),7);
        }else{
            aids = sids.split(',');
            //remove duplicates
            for(var i=0; i< aids.length; i++){
                if(id == aids[i]){
                    return;
                }

            }           
            aids.push(id);
            setCookie('sids',aids.toString(),7);
        }
    });
});

//query

if( isset($_COOKIE['sids']) && $_COOKIE['sids']!=''){
$aids = explode(',',$_COOKIE['sids']);
//validate data
foreach($aids as $k => $val){
                    if(!is_numeric($val)){
                    unset($aids[$k]);
                    }


//echo "select product_id,product_name,price,actual_price,description,index_image from mc_products_tbl WHERE status=1 AND product_id='$val'";
     $sqlpro=$con->query("select product_id,product_name,price,actual_price,description,index_image from mc_products_tbl WHERE status=1 AND product_id='$val'");    
    $products = $sqlpro->fetch_assoc(); 
   $sqlcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqlpro);
 }
  if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_info'][$products['product_id']])){
        $temp['id'] = $products['product_id'];
        $temp['name'] = $products['product_name'];
        $temp['cost'] = $products['price'];
        $temp['image'] = $products['index_image'];
        $temp['quantity'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['cart_info'][$products['product_id']] = $temp;
    }
}
```

this code is only for add product to the cart but not size, we need to add size to the cart, may i request you suggest for add size to cart.

Comment: where is the code for selecting the size?

Comment: /Size

<table><tr><td>Size:</td>
<?php 
                    for($i=0; $i<$sizecount; $i++) { ?>
 <td><button onclick="selectsize(<?php echo $arr[$i];?>)" class="add-size-cart" hef="<?php echo $arr[$i];?>" pef="<?php echo $products['product_id'];?>"><?php echo $arr[$i];?></button></td> <?php } ?></tr></table>

Comment: this is size code

Comment: Logic seems flawed to me - surely the inventory system has a different SKU for a pair of size 12 Docs to a pair of size 10s?

Comment: sorry i dint get you

Comment: why are you using buttons and not a select?

Comment: actually we no need drop down ,we need button to choose

Comment: @prudhvini you mean checkboxes

Comment: @madalin ivascu button is not mandatory if we use select what is the functionality for add size to cart

Comment: like any other input elements you need a name for the input and a submit button to send the data to the back-end for processing